# How to test on new values in LSTM in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have just created an LSTM model that predicts multidimensional numpy array using the time frame 7. The column index ranges from 1, because the 0th index column is actually a date value. Now my model does pretty well for the test set till March 2018 for which I have ground truth value. Now I wanted to predict for the next 1 year. I am stuck in this prediction part because I dont have a ground truth to feed into the model. I just have to give the next following dates. Could you please help me how this prediction can be achieved? Let me know if you need any more details other than data.
Please find the below code

```
 def build_model(NanWah):
NanWah_data_model1=NanWah
list_range=int(NanWah_data_model1.shape[0]*0.8)
rest_list_range=(NanWah_data_model1.shape[0]-list_range)
NanWah_training_set=NanWah_data_model1.iloc[:list_range,1:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))  # 0 and 1 scaling it 
NanWah_training_set_scaled=sc.fit_transform(NanWah_training_set)
X_train=[]
y_train=[]
for i in range(7,list_range):
    X_train.append(NanWah_training_set_scaled[i-7:i,:])
    y_train.append(NanWah_training_set_scaled[i])
X_train,y_train=np.array(X_train),np.array(y_train)
X_train=np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],13))
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense,Dropout,Activation
regressor=Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],13)))
#regressor.add(Dropout(0.20))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
#regressor.add(Dropout(0.20))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
#regressor.add(Dropout(0.20))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
#regressor.add(Dropout(0.20))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=False))
regressor.add(Dense(units=13))
regressor.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mean_squared_error")
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5,batch_size=10)
NanWah_test_set=NanWah_data_model1.iloc[list_range:,1:].values
inputs=NanWah_test_set
inputs=sc.transform(inputs)
X_test=[]
for i in range(7,rest_list_range):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-7:i,:])
X_test=np.array(X_test)
X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],13))
predicted_values=regressor.predict(X_test)
predicted_values=sc.inverse_transform(predicted_values)
predicted_water_m3=predicted_values[:,9:10]
predicted_electricity_kwh=predicted_values[:,7:8]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for this question. 
Here is what I did.

1. Have a numpy array which has the last n values ( where n is the time that LSTM wants to look back)
2. Append the 0th index of the numpy array again.
3. Reshape it
4. Predict the value using the model built
5. Delete the last index in the numpy array and then append the array with the predicted value
6. Continue this till you find the desired number of values for the records.

Sample code is given below:

```
inputs=Test.values  # this contains the last 60 values of the training record
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
# Scale inputs but not actual test values
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
# I am keeping it for 60 look backs and finding only 5 records
for test in range(0,5):
inputs=np.append(inputs,inputs[0])
inputs=inputs.reshape(-1,1)
print(inputs.shape)
X_test=[]
for i in range(60, 61):
    X_test.append(inputs[test:i+test,0])
# make list to array
X_test = np.array(X_test)
print(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1],1))
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)
print("for the first iteration {}".format(predicted_stock_price))
inputs=np.delete(inputs,len(inputs)-1,axis=0)
inputs=np.append(inputs,predicted_stock_price)
inputs=inputs.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Hi @SrihariRaghu . I really appreciate your work regarding this answer. I would like to ask one thing. I am facing similar kind of issue for univariate time series prediction. My problem is like this I have value till Dec-2018(monthly basis) Now I am trying to predict for next one year (2019) but not getting any luck. I also tried many methods but nothing is working out for me. Any suggestion or help from your side will be highly appreciated.